# Load top 10 books per each country into a separate table...?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables

```
TABLE #1 "users"
3 columns 
User-ID int (11)
Location varchar (250)
Age int (11)
Primary-key (User-ID)

TABLE #2 "books"
5 columns 
ISBN varchar (13)
Book-title varchar(255)
Book-author varchar (255)
Year-of-publication  int(10)
Publisher varchar (255)

TABLE #3 "Book-raitings"
3 columns
User-ID int (11)
ISBN varchar (13)
Book-rating int (11)
Primary-key (user-id, ISBN)
```

The Location column `varchar` will be of format (`city, state, country`)

I have to generate top 10 books per each country into a separate table. Generate SQL dump.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Can you change the hyphens to underscores. I keep thinking that you're trying to subtract stuff. And when it comes to homework, we typically require a little more effort.

Comment: Thank you i did notice the Hyphens after. This is actually an example i saw online i wanted to try to understand not hw . i appreciate the fast answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some initial recommendation:

1. Do not use - in MySql variable name. It will force to use this syntax: `'Book-ratings'`.`'Book-rating'` instead of: `Book_ratings.Book_rating` the sign minus is an operator in MySql.
2. It is a pity you have location as a sequence of comma separated values. It would have been much better to have 3 fields: city, state, country. This force complex string treatment and is a source of limitations.

You can create a table with the country this way:

```
CREATE TABLE books_by_country 
SELECT 
`Book-ratings`.`Book-rating`,
`books`.`Book-title`,
REPLACE(`users`.`Location`,CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`users`.`Location`, ',', 2),', '),'') as Country
FROM `Book-ratings`
LEFT JOIN `books` ON `books`.`ISBN` = `Book-ratings`.`ISBN`
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `Book-ratings`.`User-ID` = `Book-ratings`.`User-ID`;
```

From that you can pick the top 10 books for each Country this way:

```
SELECT
`books_by_country`.`Country`,
`books_by_country`.`Book-title`,
SUM(`books_by_country`.`Book-rating`) as Book_ranking
FROM `Test`.`books_by_country`
WHERE `books_by_country`.`Country`= 'USA'
Group BY `books_by_country`.`Country`,`books_by_country`.`Book-title`
ORDER BY Book_ranking DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Regards

Comment: White feather, thank you too much for you help. i did change on one of my possible solutions the location string to  have state, city, country separated it was much easier that way but i couldn't figure out how to do it without separating them. I really appreciate it your help.

Comment: Rosemary, it would be very kind if you then tick or vote the answer.